# How to test for the end of a pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *t[10]={"Program", "hjl","juyy"};
    int i;


    //printf("%c \n",*t[3]);

    int ch=*t[0];

    for(i=0;*t[i]!='\0';i++){

        printf("%d",i);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program stopped working in some time. Can anyone please explain the reason?

Comment: What are you trying to output?

Comment: `*t[i]!='\0'` --> `t[i] && *t[i]!='\0'`

Comment: The last 7 items in `t` are `NULL`,which means that you can't dereference them. Your check should therefore be done on the pointer, not on what's pointed to: `for (i = 0; t[i] != NULL; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what output you want, but probably you want to output the strings in the array.

You can't detect the end of an array directly.

You either need to put a sentinel value at the end of the array, for example `NULL`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *t[10] = { "Program", "hjl", "juyy", NULL };
                                             //^sentinel value
    int i;

    for (i = 0; t[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, t[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or you need tot count the number of elements, but this works only if the number elements of the initializer list of your `t` array is the same as the length of the array, which is not the case in your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *t[] = { "Program", "hjl", "juyy"};
         // ^ no size here means that the array will have 
         //   the size of the initalizer list (3 here),
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]); i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, t[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`sizeof(t)` is the size of the `t` array in bytes.
`sizeof(t[0])` is the size of the first element of `t`, which is here `sizeof(char*)` (size of a pointer).

Therefore `sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])` is the number of elements of the `t` array (3 here).

The output of both versions will be:

> 0: Program
>   1: hjl
>   2: juyy

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly what you are trying to output then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *t[10] = { "Program", "hjl", "juyy" };

    for ( char **p = t; *p; ++p )
    {
        for ( char *q = *p; *q; ++q ) printf( "%d ", ( unsigned char )*q );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
80 114 111 103 114 97 109 
104 106 108 
106 117 121 121
```

As the array is declared as having 10 elements and initialized explicitly with only three initializers then all other elements of the array are initialized by zeroes. You can use this fact as the condition of a loop.

Comment: That doesn't look like it's what they're trying to do at all?

Comment: @ChrisTurner It is difficult to say because we can hear the details never.:) Nevertheless the program shown in the answer shows how to test the end of the array.

Comment: I know you know, but still for those that do not read *beyond* thecode: **Such code will fail miserably if the number of elements inside the initialiser is the *same* as the number used to define the array, 10 here.**

Answer (score 1):

Define the array like this:

```
char *s[] = {
  "text 1 ...",
  "text 2 ...",
  "text 3 ...",
  NULL
};
```

Implement the functions to determine the number of elements like this:

```
#include <errno.h>

ssize_t number_of_elements(const char ** p)
{
  ssize_t e = -1; /* Be pessimistic. */

  if (NULL == p)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    char * t = p;
    while (NULL != *t)
    {
      ++t;
    }

    e = (ssize_t) (t - p);
  }

  return e;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

ssize_t number_of_elements(const char ** p)

int main(void)
{
  int ec = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  ssize_t e;

  if (-1 == (e = number_of_elements(s)))
  {
    ec = EXIT_FAILURE;
    perror("number_of_elements() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    prints("s has %zd elements.\n", e);
  }

  return ec;
}
```